# Geometric interpretation of homogeneous system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, analytic-geometry

- Why does an homogeneous system of linear equations determine a plane that passes through the origin?
- How can I be sure the the vectors that satisfy $Ax = 0$ lie on that same plane?

Comment: (1) The coordinates of the origin used as values for the unknowns satisfy the system. (2) This is not true if the matrix $A$ is the zero matrix. If the matrix is not the zero matrix, let $a_i$ be one of its non-zero rows. Then the $i$-th equation of the system is $a_i\cdot x=0$, which is saying that the vectors $x$ are perpendicular to the vector $a_i$. The set of vectors perpendicular to a fixed vector is a (hyper)plane. Therefore, all solutions of the system are inside this (hyper)plane. Of course, they are also inside the (hyper)planes determined by the other non-zero rows of $A$ too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution set of a homogenous system of linear equations is a set $S$ of vectors $\vec{v}$ whose values $v_j$ satisfy a set of $m$ equations
$$a_{1,i}v_1+a_{2,i}v_2+...+a_{n,i}v_n=0 \tag{1}$$
where $1\le i\le m$. We can see that the solution set $S$ of this system of $m$ equations (which you are calling a plane, although that name is only applicable when $m=1$ and we are working in three dimensions) passes through the origin because all equations in the form of $(1)$ are trivially true when $\vec{v}=\vec{0}$, or when $v_j=0$ for all $j$:
$$a_{1,i}\cdot 0+a_{2,i}\cdot 0+...+a_{n,i}\cdot 0=0$$

As for your second question, this depends on how exactly you define $A$ and is clearly not true in general.

Comment: Thank you. I cannot understand why your linear combination of $n$ vectors is connected with the fact that there are $n$ equations. Can you explain, please?

Comment: @F.Zer My bad, I didn’t realize that I had used the same variable for the number of equations and the number of variables. I’ve changed it to $m$ equations and $n$ variables.

Comment: Thanks. When you say, "that name would be applicable when $n = 1$", should be $m = 1$, also. Is that correct?